# Open Commonly Edited File Easily in Sublime Text 2/3

Tags: macros, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3

Can someone please tell me how I can setup Sublime Text 2 or 3 so that my `F1` key on the keyboard opens up a file that on my system sits in:

> C:/users/myname/projects/main/intranet/web.config

I have [read this](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/command_palette.html), and followed instructions on a [blog post](http://otaku-elite.com/code/2013/05/10/creating-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-sublime-to-open-specific-files/), but still cannot get it to work.

Here is what my bind looks like:

```
{ "keys": ["f1"], "command": "open_file", "args": {"file": "../../../../../../../users/myname/projects/main/intranet/web.config"} }
```

All the navigating back is because from what I can tell, Sublime starts from the Packages folder.

Is there a way I can tell it to always start navigating from `C:\`? I tried doing an absolute path like:

```
{ "keys": ["f1"], "command": "open_file", "args": {"file": "C:/users/myname/projects/main/intranet/web.config"} }
```

but I get the following path when I click `F1` and of course a blank `web.config`

```
c:\users\myname\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\C:\users\myname\projects\main\intranet\web.config
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: Can't you just specify the absolute path? {"file": "C:/Users/myname/projects/main/intranet/web.config"}?

Comment: Updated Q. I had tried that before, hence why I was asking about C:\ Thanks

Comment: Ok, what about using the *NIX-y convention and pretending C:\ is /?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, though it doesn't make sense to me :/

```
{ "keys": ["f1"], "command": "open_file", "args": {"file": "/c/users/myname/projects/main/intranet/web.config"} }
```

Xyon's final suggestion did not work, but helped me get the right answer.

Thanks